# Can't see the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code for plot a grapy with python. My problem is the image is saved but it is empty. I can't see the relevan graph. What is this problem?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
movies = ["Annie Hall", "Ben-Hur", "Casablanca", "Gandhi", "West Side 
Story"]
num_oscars = [5, 11, 3, 8, 10]
xs = [i + 0.1 for i, _ in enumerate(movies)]
plt.bar(xs, num_oscars)
plt.savefig('path/my_figure.png')
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you have a folder named 'path' ?

Comment: Also works for me, but could calling ``plt.draw()`` right before ``plt.savefig()`` help?